# generic way to convert imperative if-then-else statements into functional style?

Tags: functional-programming

[In this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/121329/resource-on-translating-imperative-programs-to-functional-programs), I asked about a reference for translating imperative code to functional code. I want to ask a more specific question here.

How, in general, do we translate into functional style, a statement of the form:

```
if (cond) then
    do x;
else
    do y;
```

I know that functional languages have if-then-else statements but the expressions are only allowed to be pure. **Is there a general way of doing this translation?**

Comment: Recursively, translate the `do x` and `do y` first.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in comments to the other question, *any* imperative program with side-effects can be *trivially* transformed into a pure program by simply lifting it into the `IO` monad, for example.

Or, by implementing an interpreter for an imperative language in a pure language.

That is, however, not good functional design. (Although, embedding a Domain Specific Language for side-effects into a program to provide *limited* and *isolated* side-effects in clearly demarcated sections of the code *could* certainly be considered good design.)

There *is no general way of doing this translation*. You need to *understand* what the *original problem* is that the program is solving, then *solve* that problem in a functional manner.